# HTML: how to: “Separate table rows with a vertical line”

Tags: html, css

I have a basic HTML table which contains table rows. My goal is to separate those table rows with a visible vertical line (for better readibility of the content).

How could I do this? Thank you.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/P2GZX/47/)

```
.line {
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}

.textRotation {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  ;
}
```

***expected result:***
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things to do here:

1. Apply a `border-right` to `.textRotation` to give you the unbroken vertical line.
2. Add a little padding to the `th`s in only the rows with data so the text is not squashed up to the line.

The actual data rows start with "Lun" in the 4th `tr` and go on to the bottom of the table, so you need to use an [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#Example_selectors) CSS selector of `n+4` and apply `padding-left` to that.

```
.textRotation {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    border-right: 2px solid black;
}

tr:nth-of-type(n+4) th
{
    padding-left:3px;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P2GZX/60/)

Comment: Which browser version are you using (Fiddle is fine for me in IE9+,FF,Chrome)? Does the JSFiddle look correct? If so, you should post the _actual_ HTML and CSS for the table or we are all working on the wrong thing.

Comment: i resolve, my problem was a   border-collapse: separate;

Answer (score 2):

try this.,

```
.textRotation {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        border-right: 3px solid;/*added one*/
      ;
```

Answer (score 0):

### [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P2GZX/54/)

```
tr:nth-of-type(n+3) th
{
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```